# How do I add more points to a polygon in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

How do I add more points to a polygon in adobe photoshop?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because at the moment, it is quite unclear what exactly your issue is. Please [edit] your question to include more detail as to what you are trying to achieve, what exactly it is you are struggling with and how the application's help files are inadequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the number in the **Control Bar** across the top of the screen before drawing.

[image]

If you've already drawn the shape, then use the **Add Anchor Point Tool** to add additional anchor points.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using the Polygon tool, press [ or ] to decrease or increase the number of sides by one.

Holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key will increase or decrease the number of sides in increments of 10.